# Sorting characters by alphabetical order within column?

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I currently have the following column:

```
Themes
toast,eggs,fruit
chocolate,eggs,milk
fruit,apple,milk
```

so this column has 3 rows, i would want the following to be made

```
Themes 
eggs,fruit,toast
chocolate,eggs,milk
apple,fruit,milk
```

Essentially to order all values within all rows to be in alphabetical order?

How can i achieve this? I have many more rows than this and i would want to keep the comma in as i need it - i know to use strinr but unsure how

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious approach, splitting the string on comma, `sort`ing it and then pasting it back together.

```
df$Themes <- sapply(strsplit(df$Themes, ","), function(x) 
                              paste0(sort(x), collapse = ","))


df
#               Themes
#1    eggs,fruit,toast
#2 chocolate,eggs,milk
#3    apple,fruit,milk
```

---

Using the same logic with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Themes = str_c(str_sort(str_split(Themes, ",",simplify = TRUE)),
                                                        collapse = ","))

#  Themes             
#  <chr>              
#1 eggs,fruit,toast   
#2 chocolate,eggs,milk
#3 apple,fruit,milk
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Themes = c("toast,eggs,fruit", "chocolate,eggs,milk", 
 "fruit,apple,milk")), .Names = "Themes", row.names = c(NA, -3L
 ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: solved independently. reached the same conclusion except saved one character `paste()` instead of `paste0()`

Comment: @snoram haha..yes, that one character could be saved here, the output would be the same.

Comment: Cheers your tidyverse answer was settled on in the end - thanks for the help much appreciated!

Comment: duly noted! have accpeted now - ddin't know how to before